# Extract script contents with BeautifulSoup (4.9.0)

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Starting with version 4.9.0 BeautifulSoup4 changed[0] the way `text` prop works, now ignoring contents of embedded scripts:

```
= 4.9.0 (20200405)
...
* Embedded CSS and Javascript is now stored in distinct Stylesheet and
  Script tags, which are ignored by methods like get_text() since most
  people don't consider this sort of content to be 'text'. This
  feature is not supported by the html5lib treebuilder. [bug=1868861]
```

So now it's no longer possible to extract `wanted text` out of html `<script>wanted text</script>` using `soup.find('script').text`.

What is the preferred way of extracting it now? I'd rather prefer not to remove `<script>` and `</script>` from `str(script)` by hand.

[0] - https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~leonardr/beautifulsoup/bs4/view/head:/CHANGELOG

Answer (score 3):

You could try using the script tag's [`contents`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children) as follows:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://www.yourwebsite.com")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

for script in soup.find_all('script'):
    if len(script.contents):
        print(script.contents[0])
```